# hardcoding primarykey value in applications

Tags: c#, sql, database, primary-key

Hi I came to this situation working in my project, where people hardcode the value of a primarykey column in an application. Is it a good practice. while dealing with environments the value of that record might change but how about using identity inserts to other environments.

Comment: No, it's never a good idea to hard-code identity values.

Comment: If an application is built in that way, do you recommend continuing to do so?

Comment: No.  If an application is already built in that way, I would change that as soon as I'm able to do that.  Hard-coding the identity values (*especially if you have multiple environments*) is just asking for there to be a problem where the values don't match between environments.  Not to mention, doing something like `SELECT * FROM SomeTable T JOIN Statuses S ON T.StatusId = S.Id WHERE S.Name = 'InProgress'` makes your intention 100% clear, whereas `SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE StatusId = 3` just creates more questions, confusion, and ultimately more work to figure out its intent.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for you response. I really appreciate you help.

Answer (score 4):

While this is obviously a very poor practice, I hesitate to reject anything like this without decent information on the reasoning.  I usually give my colleagues the benefit of the doubt and assume they have thought about the problem and come to a reasonable conclusion, and I simply need to learn to understand their reasoning.

There are certain very rare cases where hardcoded identities can be an OK solution, for example if your installation package also creates the database and the schema and seeds certain domain lookup values so they are the same on every system.  In cases like these, the identity column is defined with a seed that is a little higher than usual (e.g. `IDENTITY(100,1)`) and the system values are always placed below the seed (in this case, 100).

For example, maybe you have a domain table for `PhoneType` and values 1-3 are reserved for "Primary," "Billing," and "Contact."  Meanwhile values 100 and up are allowed for end users to define their own phone types.

It is definitely a poor practice to insert hardcoded identity values during run-time proper, e.g. in response to user input.  In that case it is probably better to find a natural key, use a GUID, or develop your own identity tracking system.

Comment: I am actually writing an application which will have an activity, i have a table for a list of activities. I have a console application for the activities, and now i got a new activity that has a different execution. So i want to identify that activity in the same console application so that i can have a different class and methods for it. Do you recommend hardcoding the activityid(Primarykey in the activity table) or the activity name?

Comment: If i use a GUID, Do you mean to maintain the same GUID in different environments?

Answer (score 2):

Typically I've seen this where there are constants in the code base (like enums for some kind of basic system types which are fundamental to the application) that are also in the database (as lookup tables).  There are some better ways to handle this, but ultimately, something is always going to get hardcoded in these cases, even if it isn't the primary key.  A primary key might be a natural key, for instance.

Typically you would only see this being acceptable for very fundamental entities.  Perhaps a type of organization or entity in a program like: TYPE_USER, TYPE_GROUP.  You would not see this for lookups which are typically user-modifiable, or expecting to be extensible, or not fundamental in some way, like VEHICLE_TYPE_CAR, VEHICLE_TYPE_SUV, VEHICLE_TYPE_RV, VEHICLE_TYPE_MOTORCYCLE, etc.

In any case, it is a code smell, and it's not a practice that's a good idea unless it's a fundamental immutable enumeration in the architecture.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with all the replies here thus far and I also face certain situations where I need to check a condition on a certain value that is based on the primary key. As Siyual has stated, checking for this condition against a more explanatory field makes more sense.

One way of dealing with this could be to add another column in the entity describing the row, and use that as a conditional check that gets mapped to an enum.

e.g. Table:

```
+-----+----------+-------------+
| PK  |  Status  | Enum_mapped |
+-----+----------+-------------+
| 101 | Fitted   |           1 |
| 201 | Unfitted |           2 |
| 301 | Used     |           3 |
+-----+----------+-------------+
```

Code:

```
private enum Statuses
{
    Fitted,
    Unfitted,
    Used
}

private int GetStatus(int enumstatus)
{
    return enumstatus = ctx.myStatus.Where(a => a.Enum_mapped == enumstatus).Select(a => a.PK).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Call the appropriate status:

```
GetStatus((int)Statuses.Fitted);
```

*Result = 101*